# Reset JS animation to steady blank canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am attempting to clear a canvas screen running JS animation from an onclick function.
Instead of reverting back to a steady blank canvas (which should remain so until triggered again), the animation starts up straight away after the clearance.

This is the coding I am using to clear the canvas

JS

```
     function clearleftcanvas()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="reset animation" onclick="clearleftcanvas()">
```

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

EDIT: Animation code

JS

```
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var W = canvas.width = 500 //window.innerWidth;
var H = canvas.height = 500 //window.innerHeight;
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*W);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*H);
var speed = 1;
function animate() {
reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame
            ;
reqAnimFrame(animate);
x += speed;
if(x <= 0 || x >= W - 300){
    speed = -speed;
    }
    draw();
}
function draw() {  
ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "clear";
function randCoord(){
return Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1);
  }
ctx.lineWidth=  Math.random() * (0.5 - 0.01) + 0.01;
ctx.moveTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.lineTo(randCoord(0),randCoord(0));
ctx.stroke();
ctx.scale(1,1)
ctx.fill();
}
animate();
</script>
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #FFFFF;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: You also need to stop the animation timer before clearing the canvas. Please post the whole code in a fiddle for better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your animation an interval and when you clear it use.

```
var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame;
window.cancelAnimationFrame(interval);
```

The code is too big to post it here but you can see a fast written working version here.
http://jsfiddle.net/4bVBa/1/